# Builded image starts and exits right after

Tags: docker

I want to create a image that I could just copy my files and use as monstly for project with my friend
I'm using this image as mirror to guide me https://hub.docker.com/r/tomsik68/xampp/dockerfile , but he has install too much and I just really want xampp...

So I can't resolve this problem right here:

As I run my builded image with command

```
 docker run -t -d -p 3000:80 xampp-model
```

Powershell returns to me:

```
95ec81d365025c0452efafe7ae91f7b50f7d469add7494c7a380bf44b8af43be
```

and

```
PS D:\Programming\myPortfolio> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              
PORTS               NAMES
PS D:\Programming\myPortfolio> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     
PORTS               NAMES
95ec81d36502        xampp-model         "sh /startup.sh"    4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago
```

my dockerfile:

```
 #image that initialize
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER bruno02souto@gmail.com

# Where will be downloaded xampp
RUN cd home

# update and upgrade to be available to install some features
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing

# curl is needed to download the xampp installer, net-tools provides netstat command for xampp
RUN apt-get -y install curl net-tools

# install wget to download xampp
RUN apt-get -y install wget

# download xampp
RUN wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.4.7/xampp-linux-x64-7.4.7-0-installer.run

# concede permission to xampp installer
RUN chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.4.7-0-installer.run

# initialize xampp installer
RUN ./xampp-linux-x64-7.4.7-0-installer.run

# remove xampp installer

RUN rm xampp-linux-x64-7.4.7-0-installer.run

# back to /
RUN cd ..

# create a dir where will be all data for webpages
RUN mkdir /www

# links previous folter to htdocs (where originally stands for web service)
RUN ln -s /www /opt/lampp/htdocs/

# copy 
COPY . /www

EXPOSE 80

RUN echo '/opt/lampp/xampp start' >> /startup.sh

CMD ["sh", "/startup.sh"]
```

and cmds to start and build that I used

```
 docker run -d -t -p 3000:80 xampp-model
 docker build -t xampp-model .
```

So, why is status is exited (0)?

Comment: If you run the `xampp start` command at a shell prompt, does it start the service in the background and immediately give you back a new prompt?  If that happens, that will in fact cause the container to exit successfully immediately, which is what you're seeing.  Try running the service directly as a foreground process, not via an init-type script.

Answer (score 0):

Your [`startup.sh`](https://github.com/tomsik68/docker-xampp/blob/193fe217be388fbd11421bcf8e63289c64968784/Dockerfile#L57-L60) ends with `/usr/bin/supervisord -n` which supposes there is something for the supervisor to... supervise.

I only see the [openssh server](https://github.com/tomsik68/docker-xampp/blob/193fe217be388fbd11421bcf8e63289c64968784/Dockerfile#L32-L36), which runs `sshd -D`: that should not exit immediately.
If it does, [configure your supervisor to run in nodaemon mode](https://superuser.com/a/1497562/141) (even though `-n` should be enough, this is safer)

I would rather use scripts similar to [`docker-lamp` `supporting_files`](https://github.com/mattrayner/docker-lamp/tree/master/supporting_files) in order to configure the supervisor for Apache explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the Dockerfile that you used the above, if you check if `startup.sh` it will become

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Which will start the stack in the background and as a result your container will `exit with status code 0`

You need to add the missing line that mentioned in Github but not in your Dockerfile.

```
RUN echo '/opt/lampp/lampp start' >> /startup.sh
RUN echo '/usr/bin/supervisord -n' >> /startup.sh
```